# Why array value is changed only after first function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a function that reverses an array:

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  for(let i = 0; i <= Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    let old = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = array[i];
    array[i] = old;
  }
  return array;
}
```

and a function that creates an local scope array and push values in reversed order:

```
function reverseArr(arr) {
  let output = [];
  for(let i of arr) {
    output.unshift(i);
  }
  arr = output;
  return arr;
}
```

Suppose there is an element:

```
let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

If i invoke the first function with arrayValue as argument, arrayValue is changed:

```
reverseArray(arrayValue); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(arrayValue); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

However if i invoke the second function with arrayValue:

```
reverseArr(arrayValue); //[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(arrayValue); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

arrayValue is not changed even if i assigned the reversed value to the argument before return:

```
arr = output;
```

can someone explain me why?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think `unshift` does what you think it does.  Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift.

Comment: See also [here](https://medium.com/@josephcardillo/how-to-reverse-arrays-in-javascript-without-using-reverse-ae995904efbe), which describes a better approach using `push`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript function not modifying array (reference?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308339/javascript-function-not-modifying-array-reference)

Comment: @RobertHarvey um.... unshift() is the correct thing to use here.... OP is reversing an array so it is appending to the front, your suggestion is adding it to the end..... So OP would get back the same array order since the loop is not going backwards....

Comment: @epascarello: In the example I linked, the loop *is* going backwards.

Comment: JS is *pass-by-value*, when you do `arr = output` you're only reassigning the local variable `arr`. You don't replace the array it used to reference nor do you affect the other variable (`arrayValue`) that still references that array. In your first example you're mutating that array directly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes and OP is not looping in reverse and your first comment is wrong.

Comment: @epascarello.   Read the example I linked; it's perfectly good code.  Instead of arguing with me, try using your time productively and post a proper answer.

Comment: My argument started because your very first comment in incorrect. And if OP follow the code in the link, it would still have the same issue because it does not alter the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `arr = output` in `reverseArr` you are referring to a new array. In other words `arrayValue` in the outer context and `arr` refer to two different objects.

You cannot change the value of the variable the function is called with. If you have a reference to the object you can mutate it, but you cannot make the outside variable refer to another object.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you take a new array with

```
let output = [];
```

and later you assign the new array to the parameter `arr`

```
arr = output;
```

Now you have two object references, one `arr` of the outer scope and a new one of `output`.

To overcome this, you need to keep the object reference of `array`. For getting a new content in an existing array, you could empty the array and push the values of the new array.

```
arr.length = 0;
arr.push(...output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your first function reverses the list ***in-place*** (i.e. operates on the list itself directly, without building a new list), while the second function reverses the list ***out-of-place***, by building a new list which contents are the reverse of the original list.

When working in-place, the changes you do to `array` inside the function are directly applied to `arrayValue`.

The reason why `arr = output` does not work the way you intend is pretty much what the other answers refer to. Namely, `arr` and `arrayValue` are two different references ("pointers"). Initially, both `arrayValue` and `arr` "point to" the same array when the function is called. However, `arr = output` makes `arr` point to the newly built list `output` instead.